# Is it possible for Block level element inside of an In-line element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

I read that in HTML, a block-level element can't be used inside of an In-line element. For example, `<span>Hi <div>!</div></span>` is not possible as `<span>` is an In-line element and `<div>` is a Block-level element.
But, I also read that `<a></a>` is an In-line element and have frequently seen `<div>` tags being used inside of a `<a>` tag. How is this possible and what am I missing?

Comment: The content model for `<a>` was changed from what it originally was.

Comment: [Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1827965/4543207)

Comment: @Redu that question is quite old. The modern HTML5 spec allows the "transparent" content model. The only things not allowed are other interactive elements (like `<button>`).

Comment: @Pointy Then it's probably better to extend that popular question with new answers covering modern HTML.

Comment: @Redu I agree with this.